# Multiple Checkbox list

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a multiple checkbox list wherein when I select the values the data should be displayed in grid. 
my problem here is when ever I select multiple data only the details of the first name in the list gets displayed
please help me

this is the code I use

```
 protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      txtSelect.Text = "";
      for (int c = 0; c < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; c++)
      {
            if (CheckBoxList1.Items[c].Selected)
            {
                txtSelect.Text += CheckBoxList1.Items[c].Text + ";" + "" + "";
            }
        }
  }
```

This is how I bind the data
 
                      
                    
                    " 
                        SelectCommand="sp_LeMS_DDL_Report" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">

Comment: How and where are you binding data to `CheckBoxList1`?

Comment: if you are binding checkbox list on page load then use `if(!isPostBack){}`

Comment: Please show us where you are binding your CheckBoxList

Comment: I want this event to be triggered as and when the user keeps selecting in the multiple checkbox. As of now my problem is ex. 2 names get displayed in the checkboxlist if both the names are selected only the details of the 1st name gets populated in the grid. I need both the details of both names to be populated. its for a report. sorry if I have not answered your question am a newbie in programming please help me. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi @Ashwin, Can you show, where you are binding data to CheckBoxList1. It will be like this- CheckBoxList1.DataSource = YourDataSource; CheckBoxList1.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to make sure you have

```
AutoPostBack = true
```

on your CheckBoxList so that your webpage can reload all of the data after changes. Then each time you change a selection the code that should be under the

```
if(isPostBack)
```

will fire. You can then add the selected values to your insert or update statements for your gridview datasource.